# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "t1"?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I've got this problem here. I'll post the link and keep in mind, that the other similar questions here couldn't helped me since I have a different code, and because of that I made this account here.

Code:

```
package secret.package.guys;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Number: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String data=scanner.nextLine(); 
    System.out.println(data);


    int a = 0; 

    while(a < 6) {
        System.out.println(a);
        a++; 
        }

    if (a > 6){ 
        System.out.println("SAFE SPACE");


    } else {
        System.out.println("Get in the Safe Space");
        System.out.println("PERSON has entered the Safe Space. Safe Space closes instantly.");
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    String s = new String("Old marks: ");
    String t = new String("5.5"); 
    String u = new String("4"); 
    String v = new String("3"); 
    String w = new String("2.5"); 
    String x = new String("6.0"); 
    String y = new String("5.2"); 
    String z = new String("4"); 

    String t1 = t.replaceAll("5.5", "6");
    String u1 = u.replaceAll("4", "4");
    String v1 = v.replaceAll("3", "5");
    String w1 = w.replaceAll("2.5", "3");
    String x1 = x.replaceAll("6.0", "2");
    String y1 = y.replaceAll("5.2", "1.8");
    String z1 = z.replaceAll("4", "4.4");
    System.out.println("New: " + s + " " + t1 + " " + u1 + " " + v1 + " " + w1 + " " 
    + x1 + " " + y1 + " " + z1);
    System.out.println("Enter new marks: ");

    int foo = Integer.parseInt("t1"); 
    int foo1 = Integer.parseInt("u1"); 
    int foo2 = Integer.parseInt("v1"); 
    int foo3 = Integer.parseInt("w1"); 
    int foo4 = Integer.parseInt("x1"); 
    int foo5 = Integer.parseInt("y1"); 
    int foo6 = Integer.parseInt("z1"); 

    System.out.println("foo1 + foo2 + foo3 + foo4 + foo5 + foo6");

}
```

}

Comment: the exception is speaking itself you are trying to convert `"t1"` string to integer which is not possible as t1 is not any representation if int instead you have to parse the variable `t1`

Comment: You should be aware that replaceAll takes a regex as first argument. Your code `    String t1 = t.replaceAll("5.5", "6");` would replace 555 and 575 to 6 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `parseInt` on the value of the String variable, not on the variable name.

For example,

```
int foo = Integer.parseInt("t1");
```

should be

```
int foo = Integer.parseInt(t1);
```

And that would only work if `t1` contains a String representation of an integer (this means `parseInt(z1)` and `parseInt(y1)` would still fail since those `String`s don't contain integers).

Answer (score 1):

Your code tries to parse a String into a numerical value.

With the value "1" it would work, but since "t1" is not a valid numerical value, it will fail, and result in this Exception.

What I assume you want is, instead of:

```
int foo = Integer.parseInt("t1");
```

where you pass "t1" as a String

```
int foo = Integer.parseInt(t1);
```

with the reference variable t1.

Comment: thank you for your answer. now I feel stupid for making such a mistake.

Comment: now I get this error line: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.8"

Comment: parse that to a double, instead of an int. it's a number with decimals, so it can't be an int

Comment: so should I write: int foo Integer.parsedouble(t1); ?

Comment: No, Double.parseDouble(t1);  (if t1 is the one with a decimal value, if it doesn't have a decimal value, Integer.parseInt will do)

Comment: okay. now I have this error line after I changed the code: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "t1"                     changed code: http://pastebin.com/uXgD9Vsu

Comment: so, you just copied back your previous error. it's t1, not "t1". And also, parsing to a float or double only has to be done for those variables that contain decimals

Comment: now i get it. only double when its 1.8 for example. the only problem is that now i can't replace the numbers (the one in String t1 = t.replaceAll("5.5", "6"); and the others. They just stay the same. @Skultuske

Comment: now i get it. only double when its 1.8 for example. the only problem is that now i can't replace the numbers (the one in String t1 = t.replaceAll("5.5", "6"); and the others. They just stay the same.

Comment: "I can't replace" ... parsing to double changes nothing to that code, so what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: well I want to when ''New:'' appears write new numbers, and these numbers should then replace the number in for example the line I mentioned. @Stultuske

Answer (score 1):

Please change your code as follows ....

```
int foo = Integer.parseInt(t1); 
int foo1 = Integer.parseInt(u1);
int foo2 = Integer.parseInt(v1); 
int foo3 = Integer.parseInt(w1); 
int foo4 = Integer.parseInt(x1); 
int foo5 = (int)Float.parseFloat(y1); 
int foo6 = (int)Float.parseFloat(z1);  

System.out.println(foo1 + foo2 + foo3 + foo4 + foo5 + foo6);
```

Comment: so, if he does this: which is the next Exception to be thrown?

Comment: I don't understand what you are taking about

Comment: He already replied to an answer that if he does that, this is the result: now I get this error line: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.8"

Comment: Ok.. Exception occured as "1.8" is float.

Comment: int foo5 = (int)Float.parseFloat(y1); 
int foo6 = (int)Float.parseFloat(z1);